# Mediaplayer is slow, how to overcome this?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, exoplayer

### Problem:

---

I've created a single-radio app with **MediaPlayer** but `prepare()` method takes too much time (12-15 Seconds) and as a result when user hits the play button he/she waits for so long.
Is there anything I can do about it(I need to make it faster)? I found **Exoplayer** but little documentation/tutorials were found about it ;/

To be more specific here is what code I've written (Strings[0] is the URL)

```
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(strings[0]);
mediaPlayer.prepare();
```

I am open to any new suggestion or ideas

Comment: try using `prepareAsync()` and `setOnPreparedListener()` instead of `prepare()`. It may solve your issue.

Comment: looks like `prepare` takes long because it it downloads from the internet.

Comment: @SahdeepSingh  I am calling prepare() inside AsyncTask, so I do it asynchronously.. The problem is that user waits too long from the time he presses  the button until he listens to the music

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko Imao 12 sec are way to many for just a radio streaming url. I tested it with another phone and it started playing the music in less than 5 sec... I don't know what's going on

Comment: probably the buffer size / stream quality is different

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko Is there any solution to overcome this issue? What would you do in my case?

Comment: I am not pretty much sure whether it will help you or not but you can try ExoPlayer. It should work for you.